# Convert systematic date to formatted date

Tags: javascript

I want to convert systematic date into readable date format. However when I pass systematic date as argument to date constructor I get `Invalid date` response. How to do this properly in order to display formatted date such as `dd-mm-yyyy` for GMT+2 ?

```
var date = message.date; // => 1466663308000
        var dateObject = new Date(date);
        console.log(dateObject);
```

Console output:

> Invalid Date

Comment: Is `systematic date` just Date in milliseconds?

Comment: Are you certain `message.date` is 1466663308000?  Looks good to me, if so.

Comment: It is date returned from Google API

Comment: Is it a string or a number? That value works fine as a number, but not if it's a string. What happens when you try `new Date(+date)`?

Comment: Nice pointing, @Pointy! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure the timestamp value is a number and not a string:

```
    var date = message.date; 
    var dateObject = new Date(+date); // note the +
    console.log(dateObject);
```

Once you've got a valid date, there are many [other questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?rq=1) about formatting dates.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code, it is absolutely correct.
I can get the correct date

```
var d=new Date(1466663308000);
document.write(d);
```

But I tried another way:

```
var x = "1466663308000";
var d=new Date(x);
document.write(d);
```

I got the "Invalid date", so I guess, `message.date` should be a string, please try to `long(message.date)`.

Comment: The issue was actually because of datatype (string rather than int)